# Is it ok to drop the constant term?

Tags: difference-in-difference

I want to estimate a DD model, in which I want to capture the treatment effect of a policy change (plane data for more than two time periods).

Therefore, I include a group variable, year dummies and a variable that states if a city adopts the policy change in a given year. The co-effcient effect of that variable should show the treatment effect.

Descriptive statistics show that a treatment effect occurs only for those cities that keep the policy change for several years. however, that group of cities in my sample is very small, around 1 per cent.

If I estimate the model without constant term, I get the expected sign for the treatment effect (should be negative) and all co-effcients are significant.

However, if I include the constant term, there is no treatment effect and also signs of other co-efficents change (in a theoretically unplausible way) and they are not significant anymore.

In such a case, is it ok to go with the model without the constant term?

Comment: By "DD" do you mean "Difference in differences"? It is always a good idea to define your acronyms at the first time of use. "DD model" might mean something else altogether!

Answer (score 5):

If including a constant term gives you coefficients that are not significant it means this variables are neutral with respect to their conditional effect and thus can be numerically either positive or negative without interpretation. If excluding a constant term gives you statistical significance this means that the variable in question has had a significant effect above and beyond a zero effect. If you ( and you should ) keep the constant the test of the variable in question is "has it had an effect above and beyond the overall mean" . There is no such thing as the "expected sign of a coefficient" unless you are doing a one-on-one (bivariate) study OR if you have multiple predictors that are orthogonal (independent) to each other. Model coefficients are collectively (conditional) reflecting the impact on Y of all the X's and thus may not reflect the pre-guessed (unconditional) effect.

Comment: Pl. indicate your model for descriptive statistics? Is it multiple regression model or structural equation ?

Comment: A transfer function which is a generalization of multiple regression